# How to check if the array is available inside the multi dimensional array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a multi dimensional array like this

```
A =  [[19, 16], [3], [8], [10], [11, 18]]
```

I want to check if my new generated array is available inside A

```
Eg. if B = [11, 18]
```

is available inside A or not.

Comment: can it be that `A` is arbitrarily deep nested? example `A = [[[[11, 18]]], 1]`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `in` *operator*.

```
A =  [[19, 16], [3], [8], [10], [11, 18]]
B = [11, 18] 
print(B in A)
```

Output

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A =  [[19, 16], [3], [8], [10], [11, 18]]

B = [11, 18]

print(B in A)
```

or

```
if B in A:
   #do something
   print("Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just use the `in` operator.

```
print([11, 18] in A)
```

Result:

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your run ' for ' or ' while ' loop or just use  Python keyword ' in ' to check:

```
A =  [[19, 16], [3], [8], [10], [11, 18]]

for i in A:
    if([11,18]==i):
        print "found"
        break
#or 
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if(A[i]==[11,19]):
        print "found"
        break  
#or
i=0
while(i<len(A)):
    if(A[i]==[11,18]):
        print "found"
        break
    i+=1
```

or

```
A =  [[19, 16], [3], [8], [10], [11, 18]]
if [11,18] in A:
    print "found"
```